# What are the better discussion sites for moral philosophy?

Tags: ethics, argumentation

I'm looking for mailing lists, web forums and other discussion sites.  I hope to participate myself, so the sites must be more-or-less openly accessible.  The topic that interests me is moral philosophy (ethics), but the sites needn't be specific to that topic, of course.  The crucial thing is the quality of conversation.  What is your short list of the better discussion sites?

Comment: what about this site, and, if your looking for discussion, the chat?

Comment: Unfortunately StackExchange "[only supports the absolute minimum amount of discussion](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/02/civilized-discourse-construction-kit.html)" for Q/A.  It's "[not a discussion forum](http://theexceptioncatcher.com/blog/2012/09/stackoverflow-is-a-difficult-community-to-participate-in/)".  But a chat site might work.  Do you know one that has good discussions of moral philosophy?

Comment: philosophy stackexchange has a chat :D, maybe you could even open a room only for moral philosophy.

Comment: Stack-exchange doesn't work well as a platform for debate or discussion. If you do come across one - please post a link.

Comment: I've never heard of such a discussion site for any large area of philosophy, unfortunately. It's not a medium philosophers have used. But it would be interesting to hear of one in any area.

Answer (score 1):

We have [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium), and we could even consider organizing group readings or discussions if that might be interesting to people. As noted in comments we can create rooms for particular themes or problems. Also mods can create "gallery" chats where only certain people can talk -- this might be helpful in terms of facilitating more structured interactions like debates.

Comment: Those would be my initial thoughts too. Plus maybe voting for book reviews & blogs; or developing/linking up with learning tools to drive up the quality of site; or having invited notable philosophers (perhaps in the process of marketing their book) to have a debate or just drop in a question or two. You're right though, this isn't the place to have this kind of discussion. Maybe try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium)?

Answer (score 1):

http://philosophyforums.com is a well-trafficked site with an area devoted to ethics.  Personally, I'm not a huge fan of the site, but it might be your best bet for an active, online philosophy discussion community.

You might also try http://philosophy.meetup.com and look into meeting up with local philosophers offline.  I don't know where you're located, but here in Columbus we've used the meetup site to arrange a monthly philosophy discussion for nearly ten years now.

Comment: My unpleasant experience with Philosophy Forums:  First I had trouble registering because their mail server is misconfigured.  Then a [site administrator](http://forums.philosophyforums.com/members/postmodern-beatnik-12267.html) removed [my post](http://forums.philosophyforums.com/threads/a-morality-that-purposes-collective-immortality-64584.html) from the ethics forum to a nondescript junk forum.  On asking why, I received 2 pages of (what seems to me) weak arguments.  I asked for permission to quote his reasoning in public and defend myself, but I received no reply.

Comment: I didn't like it there either, but it's the only well-trafficked site I know that is devoted to online discussions of philosophy.  I ran my own forum for a while, but I abandoned it years ago for reasons of time.

Comment: To set the record straight, I was eventually allowed to post.  More in [this feedback thread](http://forums.philosophyforums.com/threads/my-unpleasant-experience-with-philosophy-forums-64645.html).